# Flask Uploading + Folder Creation + FrontEnd Showing it

Tags: python, jquery, flask, file-handling, flask-mail

**My problem is the following:**

I'm creating and commercial proposal app, it should receive files in the input form, save them inside a folder named as the model.id and show them in the front end, inside the page of the proposal.

My code:

```py
@comercial.route('/NovoOrçamento', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def novo_orcamento():
    form = OrcamentoForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.validate_on_submit():
            form.to_database()

        else:
            flash('Something went wrong.')
            return redirect('./NovoOrçamento')

        if 'arquivos' not in request.files:
            flash('no files')

        files = request.files.getlist('arquivos')
        for file in files:
            if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                # My problem starts here at file.save() 

        return redirect('./Dashboard')

    return render_template('novo_orcamento.html', form=form)
```

I don't have the rest of the code because idk how to actually do it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading file in python flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31010819/uploading-file-in-python-flask)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a library for handling and managing file uploads and downloads. I would suggest looking at [Flask_uploads](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Uploads/) library. It allows you to configure multiple file models with different settings for allowed file types, allowed sizes, and where to save them (and many more).

Comment: The Flask-Uploads version on PyPi is broken since Feb 2020. Use https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Reuploaded/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Miguel Grinberg just wrote a superb blog post about exactly your problem this week:

https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/handling-file-uploads-with-flask

If you want to try it on your on, you have to save the uploaded files first, then serve them. Have a look at Flask's `send_from_directory` function.